# Javascript array items to numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've made a program that sorts numbers user inputs. The problem is that when I insert an empty space, it is stored in array as a number 0. I tried to set up several conditions to prevent this but nothing seems to work out. Any solution? 
here's a little snippet of my code where I believe the mistake occurs and where some kind of condition should be set: 
`stringArray = userInput.value.split(' ');
  numArray = stringArray.map(Number);`

Comment: `userInput.value.replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ').split(' ');` nukes empties first

Comment: @dandavis Not if a user starts with a space

Comment: mybad, this simply has to work (duh): `userInput.value.trim().split(/\s+/);`

Comment: Use parseInt to convert to String. It should return NaN

Answer (score 0):

As Javascript nature is weakly typed language, every time when you map your value and coerce it to Number in your code, JS tries to convert it to compatible types. Hence, empty space is converted to 0.

you can do multiple things in this case. The easiest one would be to get rid of any spaces before mapping.

I'd suggest filtering the array before mapping, e.g. :

```
stringArray.filter(function(value) {
  return value.trim() !== '';
}).map(Number);
```

Another idea would be to get rid of spaces before, as suggested in the comments, using `RegExp` ;)

Comment: don't see why you need `typeof` when `split()` will only produce array of strings

Comment: Yep, you're right. Unneeded sanity check. Adjusted the answer.

Comment: or simply `stringArray.filter(/./.test, /\S/).map(Number);` :p

Answer (score -1):

```
var numArray= stringArray.map(n=>parseInt(n,10));
```

Simply use parseInt which is more strict ( and returns NaN in this case).So you could Filter:

```
numArray=numArray.filter(e=>!isNaN(e));
```

Comment: parseInt() is the worst way to convert strings to numbers in JS, and that doesn't filter out empties... `window.isNaN` won't help much either: `["3424"," "].filter(isNaN).join(0)==""`

Comment: May not be integers though

Comment: n => Number(n)?

Comment: @dandavis your example has nothing todo with the upper code.

Comment: @lee kowalkowski theres a difference.

Comment: @dandavis did ive said the opposite? I filter numArray, which only contains Numbers ( and NaN which we want to filter)

Comment: @Jonasw: didn't realize they were cumulative, my bad.

Comment: @dandavis please read carefully before downvoting / commenting. Someone with 9k rep in js knows what to do ... :/

Comment: @dandavis slow is relative. I would say fast enough

Comment: why loop and make  n*4 function calls (2 native) when `userInput.value.trim().split(/\s+/);` works?

Comment: @dandavis why not? And if you really want you can reduce it to O(n);